# Dynamic Distribution Group Creation (PowerShell)

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, microsoft365

Made a script to dynamically create distribution groups from a CSV file. Creating the group, then setting some of it's parameters afterward, mainly conditionalcustomattributes to match with users and thus add as members.

Testing went well, but when I ran the script on the entire file, only a handful of groups were created correctly when it came to the Recipient Filter value.

Including screenshots to see the desired outcome which worked for some, and the outcome for most.

[This is the CSV file example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wV8c.png)

This is the script:

```
#pull secure cred#
$username = "me@contoso.com"
$pwdTxt = Get-Content "C:\temp\PSExpPw.txt"
$securePwd = $pwdTxt | ConvertTo-SecureString 
$PScred2 = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $securePwd




#Connect exchange
Connect-ExchangeOnline -credential $Pscred2


$CSVFile = import-csv "C:\Users\me\Desktop\Distro Lists\Tests\Distros.csv"

foreach ($email in $CSVFile) {

    New-DynamicDistributionGroup -Name $email.Name -Alias $email.Alias -DisplayName $email.DisplayName -PrimarySmtpAddress $email.PrimarySmtpAddress -includedrecipients "MailboxUsers"
    #start-sleep -s 3 

    $extattr6 = $email.CustomAttribute6
    $extattr3 = $email.CustomAttribute3 #($email.customattribute3).ToString()

    ##split each alias email so we can add each separately
    $proxies = $email.EmailAddresses.split(" ")

    #if ($extattr3.Length -eq 3) {
        #$extattr3 = $extattr3.PadLeft(4,"0")
                                                                           
                                                                           ##-RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled used for allowing external emails, $True=InternalOnly $False=Both
     set-dynamicdistributiongroup -Identity $email.Identity -Notes $email.Notes -EmailAddresses @{add=$proxies} -RequireSenderAuthenticationEnabled $False -ManagedBy "Me" -conditionalcustomattribute3 $extattr3 -conditionalcustomattribute6 $extattr6
    #set-dynamicdistributiongroup -Identity $email.Alias -Notes $email.Notes -HiddenFromAddressListsEnabled $False -ManagedBy "Me" -conditionalcustomattribute3 $extattr3 -conditionalcustomattribute6 $extattr6
    #get-dynamicdistributiongroup -Identity $email.alias | select alias,name,displayname,identity
   # }

}
```

Expected this:
[Recipient Filter shows customattributes separated by "-or" as they're comma delimited in the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPArd.png)

Results for most:
[Recipient Filter updated with what seems like the cell string, and didn't separate the values accordingly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Hf5.png)

Not sure what I'm doing wrong or what specifically it needs when setting the customattributes since only a handful got created that look like the Expected Recipient Filter.

Help?

Comment: Looks more like an issue with the data format stored in Excel. Does it work if you use an array instead of comma separated values? i.e. $extattr6 = $email.CustomAttribute6.Split(",")

Comment: In regard to the Recipient Filter updating correctly, that worked!

Gonna give it some time to pull in members for the test distro I used it on just to be sure. 

Either way, progress!

Thanks!